# How to share fast memory between a C# process and a unmanaged C process?

Tags: c#, opencv, memory, unmanaged, shared

I want to achieve a solution (VS2010) compounded by two processes:
-  a "real time image processing" process, using OpenCV in C++ unmanaged.
- and a windows GUI proccess, frendly and good looking, in C# managed.

The C++ process must be FAST (high priority performance), and the C# just a good looking window display (low priority performance)...
The idea is to share necesary data between the processes..

The data to share could be some preview live video, some image, and some values (results of image processing).

Please if anybody have some lines of code to share, or help, I will be grateful..

Comment: The typical way to share memory across processes in Windows is to use a [memory mapped file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366556(v=vs.85).aspx). Of course, you'll need the [.NET API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) as well.

Comment: @Jim: That looks like a perfectly good answer.

Comment: It isn't clear why you need two processes... why not load the C++ code in-process as a DLL?  Priorities are assigned per-thread...

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to share memory across processes in Windows is to use a [memory mapped file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Of course, you'll need the [.NET API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) as well.